# How to alias a hostname?

Tags: networking, dns, hosts, alias

Is it possible to keep a network alias - without specifying the IP address in the hosts file? For instance, I have `abcd.efgh.com` but want `abcd -> abcd.efgh.com` so that `ping` and `ssh` work as they normally would.

I want it to work with dynamic IP on abcd.efgh.com, that's why I don't want to state the IP address explicitly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A slightly less convienent way is to set up aliases for both `ping` and `ssh`, for example:

```
alias pingfoo="ping foohost.domain.tld"
```

---

OpenSSH supports adding hostname aliases (and many more options) to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host foo
    Hostname foohost.domain.tld
    # You can also add User, Port, every possible ssh(1) option.
```

Comment: Excellent; I can do without ping now that I think of it, 99.9 % of my use is ssh.

Answer (score 4):

With `dnsmasq`'s option `--cname=<cname>,<target>` you can make a CNAME that indicates that `<cname>` is actually `<target>`. Note that this works only if the DNS name of `<target>` is known to dnsmasq (either in hosts file or through DHCP).

If dnsmasq doesn't work, [Unbound](http://www.unbound.net/) is a DNS resolver that supports also unknown targets in a similar situation.

Comment: That's in DNS, not in the hosts file.

Comment: @mpez0: It would still work (dnsmasq is intended to be run on one's LAN or a personal computer, as a caching DNS resolver)

Answer (score 3):

If your OS uses GNU *glibc*, you can use its `$HOSTALIASES` feature.

From the manual page of `gethostbyname(3)`:

```
DESCRIPTION

       [etc etc etc] If name doesn't end in a dot and the environment variable
       HOSTALIASES is set, the alias file pointed to by HOSTALIASES will first
       be searched for name (see hostname(7) for the file format). The current
       domain and its parents are searched unless name ends in a dot.
```

This works with both `gethostbyname()` and the newer `getaddrinfo()`; however, it doesn't seem to affect `ping` at all...

Comment: Unfortunately not using libc.

Comment: It doesn't affect ping because ping has setuid set and HOSTALIASES only works with executables that don't have this flag. If you already are root it works, but not when using ping as a normal user.

Comment: [Can't alias hostname to IP address](https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/glibc/+bug/1483187).